# How create a loop with Scrapy?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get("https://marketplace.ifood.com.br/v1/merchants?latitude=-22.7556&longitude=-43.4603&channel=IFOOD")
content = response.content
merchants = json.loads(content)['merchants']

restaurant_id = merchants[0]['id']
restaurant_id

response = requests.get(f"https://marketplace.ifood.com.br/v1/merchants/{restaurant_id}/extra")
content = response.content
restaurant_info = json.loads(content)
```

I need a loop that takes every *restaurant_id* and goes through the url to get the data. It is possible?

I tried a few ways but got the error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with `scrapy`, is your question really about how to create a loop in python?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Scrapy you need to import scrapy, and create a spider.

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/examples.html

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#a-shortcut-to-the-start-requests-method